# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$, is $\lambda^2$ an eigenvalue for $T^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

For matrices this is true, but I'm not sure whether it applies to more general transformations. Here $T$ is a finite measure-preserving transformation. From the definition of eigenvalues, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then there exists a nonzero a.e. function $f \in L^2$ such that $f(T(x)) = \lambda(f(x))$ a.e.

Then we have that $f(T^2(x)) = f(T(T(x)) = \lambda f(T(x)) = \lambda \cdot \lambda f(x) = \lambda^2 f(x)$. Does this logic hold?

Comment: Note that $T$ induces a bounded linear isometry $I_T$ on $L^2(\mu)$, given by $f \mapsto f \circ T$. The condition that $f(T(x))=\lambda f(x)$ a.e. is equivalent to the statement that $f$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $I_T$ in the usual sense of linear maps. Hence, it is true.

Answer (score 1):

One has to add one detail: let $A = \{ x : f(T(x)) = \lambda f(x) \}$. Then $A$ is of full measure and $f(T^2(x)) = \lambda^2 f(x)$ whenever $x \in A$ and $T(x) \in A$, i.e. $x \in A \cap T^{-1}[A]$. Since $T$ is measure-preserving, this set is also of full measure, so the equality holds almost everywhere.

Comment: Why does $A$ have to have full measure here?

Comment: @ppap That is exactly what $f(T(x)) = \lambda f(x)$ almost everywhere means: that the set of $x$ for which the equality holds is of full measure.

Comment: I see what the argument is now, thank you!